# Django - getting object with unicode in field value

Tags: python, django, unicode

In my Word model (with single field called 'name'), I create a first row with a name that contains a unicode character:

```
In [1:] Word.objects.create(name=u'à')
Out[1:] <Word: à>
```

When I filter with name='a', I'm expecting no result. This is not what's happening:

```
In [2:] Word.objects.filter(name=u'a')
Out[2:] <Word: à>
```

Opposite is also a problem: when I create the word 'e' and filter with name=u'é', I'm getting the 'e' word.

Anyone has an explanation?

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server. Note: the accented character is well stored in the database.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Comment: You need to set the collation on your database appropriately - that defines how the database orders and compares text. It's kind of a large topic, this looks like a reasonable starting point for SQL Server: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: You are right Peter. Setting the good collation for the column name (accent sensitive) solves the problem. Thanks to all.